# Run only if geo-info available in python

Tags: python, flickr

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
import flickrapi

api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
secret_api_key = "xxxxxxxxxx"
flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, secret_api_key)

def obtainImages3():

    group_list = flickr.groups.search (api_key=api_key, text = 'Paris', per_page = 10)

    for group in group_list[0]:

        group_images = flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos (api_key=api_key, group_id = group.attrib['nsid'], extras = 'geo, tags, url_s')

        for image in group_images[0]:
        url = image.attrib['url_s']
        tags = image.attrib['tags']

        if image.attrib['geo'] != 'null':

            photo_location = flickr.photos_geo_getLocation(photo_id=image.attrib['id'])
            lat = float(photo_location[0][0].attrib['latitude'])
            lon = float(photo_location[0][0].attrib['longitude'])
```

I want to get information about images if and only if they have a geo-tag connected to them. I tried to do this with the line if image.attrib['geo'] != 'null' but I don't think this works. Can anyone suggest a way I might be able to do it, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Replace your if image.attrib['geo']!='null' condition with a try and exception block as below.
Since the API returns the data in JSON format you can check the presence of key using:

```
try:
    image.attrib['geo']
    photo_location=flickr.photos_geo_getLocation(photo_id=image.attrib['id'])
    lat = float(photo_location[0][0].attrib['latitude'])
    lon = float(photo_location[0][0].attrib['longitude'])
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, where would I fit that in in my code(sorry for the stupid question I am new to this haha)

Comment: I am not sure if this is working as I am not getting an error - KeyError: 'url_s'

Comment: What do you mean you are not getting an error? The Key now you have specified is different from the one you originally posted

Comment: I have edited to exactly as you posted and the error I am getting now is stating a key not relevant- KeyError: 'url_s'

Comment: Put url = image.attrib['url_s'] in the try block it will work,but then you will get images which have both urls and geocode keys.